# Python : Exception handling in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
w1=webdriver.Firefox()
def f1():
    w1.get("dagsb.com")
def f2():
    w1.get("google.com")
```

I have the above code snippet. I want to try to call `f1()` and if it throws an error (which it does as dagsb.com doesnt exist) I want to call `f2()`

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try` and `except` to handle *webdriver-specific errors*:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

try:
    w1.get("http://dagsb.com")
except WebDriverException as e:
    # TODO: log exception
    w1.get("https://google.com")
```

Note that this is not going to handle Page not found 404 - since in that case, there would not be an exception thrown. The idea would be to check the page title not to equal "Page not found":

```
is_found = w1.title != page_not_found_message
if not is_found:
    w1.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: My browser opens and says page not found on the server. It doesn't open google.com

Comment: @JoeMcKinzie okay, updated the answer, please check.